# Add headers to csv file using python and AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I've been trying to figure out a way to add headers to a csv file using an AWS lambda function. The actual file contains sensitive info so I've been playing with a csv sample from the internet. I cannot use pandas as we haven't set up that layer yet so I can only work with 'requests' and 'csv'.

The basic get request gets me the data:

```
 import boto3
 import os
 import requests
 from base64 import b64decode
 import botocore
 import csv 
 import json 
 import fileinput

 def lambda_handler(event, context):
     url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
     query = requests.get(url)
     print (query.text)
```

Result:

```
 Response:
 null

 Request ID:
 "2c17f3a7-e00f-4301-a647-51a66e755b17"

 Function Logs:
 1998,Nagano,Bobsleigh,Bobsleigh,GBR,four-man,M,Bronze
 1998,Nagano,Biathlon,Biathlon,GER,15km,W,Bronze
 1998,Nagano,Biathlon,Biathlon,GER,4x7.5km relay,M,Gold
 1998,Nagano,Biathlon,Biathlon,GER,4x7.5km relay,W,Gold
 1998,Nagano,Biathlon,Biathlon,GER,7.5km,W,Bronze
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
 import boto3
 import os
 import requests
 from base64 import b64decode
 import botocore
 import csv 
 import json 

 def lambda_handler(event, context):

     url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'

     query = requests.get(url)

     with open('/tmp/medals.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f:
         r = csv.reader(f)
         data = [line for line in r]

     with open('/tmp/medals.csv','w',newline='') as f:
         w = csv.writer(f)
         w.writerow(['user', 'first', 'last', 'email', 'local', 'membership', 'login'])
         w.writerows(data)
         return f
```

Among the many different errors, I'm giving up on this one:

```
  Response:
 {
   "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/medals.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> is not JSON serializable",
   "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError"
 }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you trying insert your header and existing csv content into a new file?

Comment: @ArunK Yes, I haven’t found another way in lambda.

Comment: the other file already has a header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go. the idea is to read the csv and make it a list by using the comma delimiter. Then using write rows to write the entire rows. I had to delete the first element of the list to remove the existing header.

```
import boto3
import os
import requests
from base64 import b64decode
import botocore
import csv
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'

  with requests.Session() as s:
      download = s.get(url)

      decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')

      cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
      my_list = list(cr)

      with open('/tmp/medals.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(['user', 'first', 'last', 'email', 'local', 'membership', 'login'])
        # delete the existing header
        del my_list[0]
        w.writerows(my_list)
```

hope this helps

Comment: I think this is what you want, check and let me know.

Comment: It worked! Now I'm now encountering an issue with the output csv, it's missing about half the records. Let me know if you would like me to post a question with more details.